# How to open an HttpURLConnection via proxy on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, proxy, httpurlconnection, http-proxy

I want to open an HttpURLConnection via proxy on google app engine.
I'm using java.

I've tried using the following methods.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xxxxxx", 3128));  
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

However it shows exception

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "xxxx:3128" "connect,resolve")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:565)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
```

And I tried another method

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "xxxxx");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
```

And it doesn't work at all.

When i run GAE with Proxy using personal computer(not deploy to cloud) , it shows

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Google App Engine does not support the use of proxies.
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.openConnection(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:54)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalURLFetchServiceStreamHandler.openConnection(LocalURLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:77)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I'm wonder is there a way can let me open an HttpURLConnection via proxy on google app engine using java?

Thank you!

Comment: Does "telnet xxxxxx 3128" work?

Comment: you mean at my personal computer? It works.

Comment: executed on the same machine where the java program fails.

Comment: I think the problem is GAE's JRE, seems it doesn't want you to use proxy.

Comment: some things you can't do on GAE. The message is quite clear - "Google App Engine does not support the use of proxies."

Comment: Is there any way that i can do to break this rule? Like using another lib for connection instead java.net or write own connection start from socket? Will there work?

Comment: you vs google engineers? You'd be better off using AWS or something then banging your head against this particular wall I think.

Comment: Thank you. I moved my application to openshift. And it worked well.